# Can't login to MacBook Pro, password and password reset not working

Tags: macos, password, login, administrator

I am helping a friend who was deleting some files and `sudo` stopped working for him.  He reset his computer and can't log back in.  First he gets-

```
Reset password using Apple ID credentials
```

I enter this in and hit reset password.  Then I get:

```
If you can change the password for this user account, you 
will create a new keychain to store the user's passwords.

The users's previous keychain still exists.  If you find the
previous password, you can access the previous keychain and 
the information and passwords it contains
```

Then I hit “OK.” This now boots the computer into Recovery Mode

From inside Recovery, I get the activation lock message:

```
If you can't log in to your computer because you forgot your
password you can reset it now.
```

Here is enter my Apple ID which I have already verified it’s valid on another computer  and enter my password.

I get the following message:

```
If you do not know the password for an admin user, the reset
operations requires resetting the passwords of all accounts 
on the system*.
```

I set a password for each user then hit *Next*. I then get an error message that it

```
could not verify credentials because directory server does 
not support the requested authentication method
```

---

From here I next logged in as another user on and went to *System Preferences => Groups* and I was able to change the password for the user I was not able to get into, but I still can't log in.  I've tried every type of reset as well.

---

Does anyone know of anything else I can try?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the Mac you’re trying to do the password reset attached to *your* Apple ID or a different one?

Comment: Its attached to his Apple ID

Comment: That’s likely the issue.  Do the reset again, but with his AppleID instead.

Comment: The rest was with his appleID.   This is his computer.  I am just posting the question since I tried to help him.   Everything was with his information.  I am just a programmer trying to help him out

Comment: Ok..but all I’m saying is the part where you used *your* Apple ID, you should use his instead.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, again logged in with the correct Apple ID.